# Where is a good place to keep a variable that only changes once a month besides a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I want to create a model for it with a single attribute but I feel like maybe there's a better way to go about it?

Comment: It depends. How do you want to change the variable front-end? Do you want to track change/have an audit trail? Does it need to be validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible ways to handle your case:

1. **config file:**
   You could create a config yml-file for example and save the variable value there. After that run a cronjob or something similar to update these value monthly. But this is just one way to handle your case.
2. **database:**
   Simple create a settings_table with attributes "value" and "identifier" in your database and for example a Setting model. In your normal model create a method where the Setting.where(:identifier => "your-special-identifier-token").first returns your monthly changed value. Update the settings_table through delayed-job gem or a cron
3. **model constant:** 
   You also could create a constant in you model, monthly update this constant and deploy your application. This is a possibility, but I think it is not really good, because you have to update directly your code.

I would recommend number 1 or 2.

Comment: 1 and 2 seems like the best approaches.

Comment: Thanks, that's the input I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use redis to stash data like this. Other key value stores will work nicely too. No need to have all the ActiveRecord / ActiveModel stuff unless you require validation.

If you are running on Heroku you could use environment variables too